# Counter example of inverse function theorem in case of non-Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples

If I consider the inverse function theorem for Banach spaces, I'd like to know if there is an counter-example where I could weaken my space to a non-complete space, like: $\mathbb{R}[X]$ for any norm.

I could use $(C[0, 1], \Bbb R) \to (C[0, 1], \Bbb R)$ using different norms and the identity as a counter example.

But I'd like to have the same space using the same norm.

Bonus if the inverse of the function is not continuous.

I know that [Inverse Operator Theorem, counter example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1824196/inverse-operator-theorem-counter-example) gives a counter-example, but it's using different norms.

Comment: Consider the space $c_{00}(\Bbb N)$ of finite complex (or real) sequences with sup-norm or $\ell^p$ norm and the diagonal map given by
$$(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}\mapsto (2^{-n} x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}.$$
This map is bounded, linear and bijective. The inverse is however not bounded and so not continuous.

Comment: @s.harp Is it possible to have a differential which is a C^1-diffeomorphism?